# Dynamic Update for 2D Random Walk

Tags: plotting, dynamic, random, animation

I have code for a random walk

```
pt = Accumulate[{Sin@#, Cos@#} & /@ RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, 1000]];
boundary = {Min@pt, Max@pt};
Norm@Last@pt;
ListLinePlot[pt, PlotRange -> {boundary, boundary}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

which produces something like this:

[image: Random Walk]

I want to try to animate this, so that I can see how the random walk updates step by step with each new coordinate. I tried using `DynamicUpdating` but I couldn't really get it to work. Is there any way to achieve this? Any help is extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `ListAnimate`.
Also, you can make your path generation a bit simpler with `AnglePath` and your bounds are not correct as Min/Max will read from any coordinates, so I've used `BoundingRegion` instead:

```
pt = AnglePath[RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, 1000]];
bbox = Transpose[BoundingRegion[pt] /. Cuboid -> List];
ListAnimate[
 ListLinePlot[Take[pt, #], PlotRange -> bbox, AspectRatio -> 1] & /@ 
  Range[1, Length@pt]
 ]
```

[image: random walk animation]

Or alternatively, use a `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot[Take[pt, i], PlotRange -> bbox, AspectRatio -> 1],
 {i, 1, Length[pt], 1}
]
```